# jquery return value of input to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, onkeyup

I'm trying to make a variable equal the value of the text box. I have the text box value being set to a variable and returned as an alert (for now) but I can't figure out how to call that variable from other functions.

```
$('#max_char').keyup(function () {
    var max_char = $(this).val();
    alert(max_char + ' Handler for .keyup() called.');
});

var count_options = {
    'maxCharacterSize': max_char,
    'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
    'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
    'warningNumber': 40,
    'displayFormat': '#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words'
};

$('#textinput').textareaCount(count_options);
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea cols="68" rows="21" name="textinput" id="textinput"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="textbox" id="max_char" name="max_char" value="-1" /> Max Characters <br/>
```

Any help would be great. Trying to add the var max_char to the maxCharacterSize of count_options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is declare `max_char` in a higher scope, i.e. *outside* of the keyup function:

```
var max_char;

$('#max_char').keyup(function () {
    max_char = +$(this).val();
    alert(max_char + ' Handler for .keyup() called.');
});
```

Also note that I put a `+` in front of `$(this).val()` to convert it from a string into a number, since `"1" + 1 == "11"`.

---

**Update**:

The reason the `textareaCount` plugin isn't working is because it is initialised *once*, on document ready. At this time, `max_char` is nothing because the user hasn't typed anything yet.

You'd have to either reconfigure or re-initialise the plugin on every keyup to get the effect you're after. Unfortunately the plugin doesn't document an easy way to do this. After digging through the plugin's source code, I think there are only 3 events it binds that you need to revert, before you can simply re-initialize it again. Try this out:

```
var count_options = {
    'maxCharacterSize': 100, // Just some default value
    'originalStyle': 'originalDisplayInfo',
    'warningStyle': 'warningDisplayInfo',
    'warningNumber': 40,
    'displayFormat': '#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words'
};

// Initialise the plugin on document ready
$('#textinput').textareaCount(count_options);

$('#max_char').keyup(function () {
    var max_char = +$(this).val();
    count_options.maxCharacterSize = max_char;

    // Unbind the 3 events the plugin uses before initialising it
    $('#textinput')
        .next('.charleft').remove().end()
        .unbind('keyup').unbind('mouseover').unbind('paste')
        .textareaCount(count_options);
});
```

Comment: Humm... this still isn't working for me. I wonder if it's a problem with the plugin http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp

Comment: @Bandon, I think I've found the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked but each keyup it reinitialize the value and adds a new line of "#input Characters | #left Characters Left | #words Words" maybe I'll try another plugin. I'm not set on this one just the first one I found.

Comment: for a demo see here: http://writer.knowconceptdesign.com/ It also seems to be binding the max_chars one behind the active input.

Comment: @Bandon, there are two things you can do: one is that you've put the code that modifies `count_options.maxCharacterSize` *after* the code that calls `.textareaCount(count_options)` - it should be before it. You can also remove the `div` that the plugin uses so duplicates aren't created. I've modified my code to show that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, if you declare the var within the global scope of javascript

Or if you directly access the input with

```
$("#max_char").val()
```

Comment: +1, I didn't realise that the whole keyup binding probably isn't needed.

Comment: I used bind on keyup to ensure that it changed dynamically with user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
parseInt($('#max_char').val())
```